# KDB/Q: how to combine the values in multiple columns and sort the values?

Tags: kdb

I would want to create a new column that contains the values of multiple columns, but these values would be sorted. See the example table below. and the type of the columns is `C`

```
name1   name2       name3       wanted
David   Barca       Alpha       Alpha Barca David
Sydney  Melbourne   Adelaide    Adelaide Melbourne Sydney
1201    21204       5601        1201 21204 5601
```

Comment: Your question is likely getting down voted because you show no attempt to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
q)update wanted: " " sv/: asc each flip (name1;name2;name3) from t
name1    name2       name3      wanted
-----------------------------------------------------------
"David"  "Barca"     "Alpha"    "Alpha Barca David"
"Sydney" "Melbourne" "Adelaide" "Adelaide Melbourne Sydney"
"1201"   "21204"     "5601"     "1201 21204 5601"
```

If you `wanted` a nested list rather than a single string, you could just leave off the `sv` part:

```
q)update wanted: asc each flip (name1;name2;name3) from t
name1    name2       name3      wanted
---------------------------------------------------------------
"David"  "Barca"     "Alpha"    "Alpha"    "Barca"     "David"
"Sydney" "Melbourne" "Adelaide" "Adelaide" "Melbourne" "Sydney"
"1201"   "21204"     "5601"     "1201"     "21204"     "5601"
```